# Selenium IDE: pick up a database value

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I made a test case with Selenium IDE that makes 25 addresses using a while-loop; starting with housenumber 1.

What I actually would like is that the maximum housenumber is picked up from the database, so we can reuse this case endlessly.

In SQL: select max(housenumber) from tbl_address where streetname = ‘Testingstreet’;

Is this possible, and if so… how?.

Comment: I am afraid you will have use some programming language for that and export your test to WebDriver

Comment: This is way outside the scope of the IDE. You have reached a point where the IDE is not capable of doing what you want your tests to do, therefore you will either have to workaround this issue somehow, or (better IMO), scrap the IDE altogether and use WebDriver & a programming language directly.

Comment: Either of these two comments above should have been an answer. You can't do it in IDE, you need an actual programming language. Pick one and then google how to connect to a database from it.

Answer (score 4):

(As **Slanec** pointed out, the comments should probably be an answer).

This is way outside the scope of the IDE. You have reached a point where the IDE is not capable of doing what you want your tests to do, therefore you will either have to workaround this issue somehow, or (better IMO), scrap the IDE **altogether** and use WebDriver & a programming language directly.

I would use the IDE to export your current tests into whatever language you want, then use the language to find out some library or API that allows you to connect to the database.

Usually, keeping to the **same** programming language and database libraries as your application under test uses, is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

One way around the limitations in IDE is to create an internal webpage that you can pass queries through to your db and return the response as a table. Interacting through that page would get you the data you need.

Like the answers before me, I suggest going with the WebDriver, but if you MUST use IDE this could be a solution for you!